# Jpa Specification IN Clause on joined property not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

We have encountered weird behavior when using JPA Specification. So we wanted to do a where clause on a joined property, so that we only fetch items where a property of a joined item matches the filter. Running the generated query on a database by SQL works as expected, however in Spring JPA doesn't seem to execute the filtering.

**Description**

**Situation**: Having two entities with each 1 sub-entity saved in the database. Both have a property with different values. We want, through JPA specification, filter on the value of one of the sub-entities.

**Expected Result**: The database only returns the entity for which the query on the property of the sub-entity matches.

**Actual Result**: The database returns both entities, even the one where the value of the property doesn't match.

Here is the code for this:

**Entities**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="item")
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ItemEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "item_number")
    private String itemNumber;
    @Column(name = "edition")
    private String edition;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="item_number",  referencedColumnName = "item_number")
    private List<PlmItemInfoEntity> plmItemInfoEntity;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ItemStatus status;
    private String fsi;
    private String sqa;
    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private Long creationDate;
    @Column(name = "modified_date")
    private Long modifiedDate;
    @Column(name = "plm_refresh_date")
    private Long plmRefreshDate;

    public PlmItemInfoEntity getLatestPlmInfoEntity() {
        // TODO Clarify what the "latest" item is -- QAP-63
        return plmItemInfoEntity.get(0);
    }

    @PrePersist
    void createdAt() {
        this.creationDate = this.modifiedDate = ZonedDateTime.now().toEpochSecond();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    void updatedAt() {
        this.modifiedDate = ZonedDateTime.now().toEpochSecond();
    }
}


@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name="plm_item_info")
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class PlmItemInfoEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "item_number")
    private String itemNumber;
    @Column(name = "item_name")
    private String itemName;
    private String edition;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PlmItemStatus status;
    private Long date;

    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private Long creationDate;
    @PrePersist
    void createdAt() {
        this.creationDate  = ZonedDateTime.now().toEpochSecond();
    }
}
```

**Specification**

```
public class ItemSpecification extends AbstractSpecification<ItemEntity> {

    private ItemFilter filter;

    public ItemSpecification(ItemFilter filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<ItemEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
            CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        query.distinct(true);
        Predicate base = cb.isTrue(cb.literal(true));

        Join<Object, Object> plmItemInfoEntityJoin = root.join("plmItemInfoEntity", JoinType.INNER);

        final Subquery<Number> subquery = query.subquery(Number.class);
        final Root<PlmItemInfoEntity> creationDateConstraint =
                subquery.from(PlmItemInfoEntity.class);
        subquery.select(cb.max(creationDateConstraint.get("creationDate")));
        subquery.groupBy(creationDateConstraint.get("creationDate"),
                creationDateConstraint.get("itemNumber"));

        base = cb.and(base, cb.in(root.get("plmRefreshDate")).value(subquery));
    
        base = cb.and(base, plmItemInfoEntityJoin.get("itemName").in(filter.getItemName()));
    

        return base;
    }
}
```

**Filter Object**

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ItemFilter implements Serializable {

    private DatePair date;
    private List<String> itemName = new ArrayList<>();

    public Optional<DatePair> getDate() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(date);
    }

}
```

**Entities after saved to database**
[image]

[image]

**Filter**
[image]

**Jpa Sql Console Query**

```
2021-10-04 11:19:48.893 CID:DEBUG 15140 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        distinct itementity0_.id as id1_0_,
        itementity0_.creation_date as creation2_0_,
        itementity0_.edition as edition3_0_,
        itementity0_.fsi as fsi4_0_,
        itementity0_.item_number as item_num5_0_,
        itementity0_.modified_date as modified6_0_,
        itementity0_.plm_refresh_date as plm_refr7_0_,
        itementity0_.sqa as sqa8_0_,
        itementity0_.status as status9_0_ 
    from
        item itementity0_ 
    inner join
        plm_item_info plmiteminf1_ 
            on itementity0_.item_number=plmiteminf1_.item_number 
    where
        ?=1 
        and (
            itementity0_.plm_refresh_date in (
                select
                    max(plmiteminf2_.creation_date) 
                from
                    plm_item_info plmiteminf2_ 
                group by
                    plmiteminf2_.creation_date ,
                    plmiteminf2_.item_number
            )
        ) 
        and (
            plmiteminf1_.item_name in (
                ?
            )
        )
Hibernate: 
    select
        distinct itementity0_.id as id1_0_,
        itementity0_.creation_date as creation2_0_,
        itementity0_.edition as edition3_0_,
        itementity0_.fsi as fsi4_0_,
        itementity0_.item_number as item_num5_0_,
        itementity0_.modified_date as modified6_0_,
        itementity0_.plm_refresh_date as plm_refr7_0_,
        itementity0_.sqa as sqa8_0_,
        itementity0_.status as status9_0_ 
    from
        item itementity0_ 
    inner join
        plm_item_info plmiteminf1_ 
            on itementity0_.item_number=plmiteminf1_.item_number 
    where
        ?=1 
        and (
            itementity0_.plm_refresh_date in (
                select
                    max(plmiteminf2_.creation_date) 
                from
                    plm_item_info plmiteminf2_ 
                group by
                    plmiteminf2_.creation_date ,
                    plmiteminf2_.item_number
            )
        ) 
        and (
            plmiteminf1_.item_name in (
                ?
            )
        )
```

**Bind Variables**

```
2021-10-04 11:45:23.923 CID:TRACE 14328 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BOOLEAN] - [true]
2021-10-04 11:45:23.925 CID:TRACE 14328 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [TOFIND]
```

**Actual Result**

[image]

**Result when running the sql on staging database**

The data on staging:
[image]

The result when running the query there:
[image]

So as you can see, the query works on staging if you run it plainly, without JPA/Hibernate. So what is going on here? How do we fix this?

More info needed or questions, please let me know. We are stuck on this one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please also log the bind variables to see what's passed by hibernate: set org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder to trace

Comment: I would say it's ?=1  and the parameters value is true

Comment: And this comes from  Predicate base = cb.isTrue(cb.literal(true));

Comment: We have used the same query for other fields, but it isn't a problem for those. It is specific for this field it isn't working.